# Dissable buttonset on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to disable a complete buttonset on button click using jquery

Until now I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ntenisOT/5Hvvn/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#radio").buttonset();
    $("#disable").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#radio").buttonset( "option", "disabled", true );
    });
    $("#enable").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#radio").buttonset( "option", "disabled", false);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Hvvn/5/

Comment: Can I re-enable the buttonset if I click again? is that possible?

Comment: See the updated code. You could easily add some logic to a single button to check the option status, if disabled, set to false, else set to true